# Using pure JS to filter checked checkboxes into a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to filter difficulty based on checked checkboxes. I have been searching a while looking for results or directions to a result, to no avail.

**Research**

Below is a piece of code that seems to work well, however using `this` does not work for pure JS. I have seen a way to do a `for ( i = 0; i < difficultyFi.length; i++ )` but I feel like I am doing something wrong with that.

I have only ever used jQuery, very little of pure JS, so trying to get a similar result has turned out to be rather difficult.

**Result**

I am searching for all `.difficultyFi` elements, getting their values which results in all `availableDifficulty`, pushing their values to a JSON array. From there I find which checkboxes are `:checked` then push values of those remaining to another JSON array called `activeDifficulty`.

**Conclusion**

Once this has been accomplished, I aim to filter my main JSON array using the `activeDifficulty` array above. This is something I will tackle in the future haha!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Filter difficulty

var availableDifficulty = [];
var activeDifficulty = [];
var difficultyFi = document.querySelectorAll('.difficultyFi');
console.log( difficultyFi );

difficultyFi.forEach( function() {
    
    var difVal = this.value();
    
    availableDifficulty.push( difVal );
    console.log( difVal );
    
    if ( this.hasAttribute( 'checked' ) ) {
        activeDifficulty.push( difVal );
        console.log( difVal );
    }
    
});
```

Comment: What is your expected output? something like (for 5 checkboxes, 2 checked) `availableDifficulty = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]` and `activeDifficulty = [1, 1]` or ???

Comment: I actually feel really silly as I JUST found the solution. The expected result was to get the `value` of each checked checkbox. My 3 difficulty values being `d_e` for easy, `d_m` for moderate and `d_h` for hard. I will answer my own question and you will see how basic the result was....jeez I feel silly haha!

Answer (score 1):

You can use few short helper functions. Spread operator `[...checkboxes]` is used to convert arraly-like `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` to real array so you can run `map` on it. Map is used to create the array of objects with checkbox elements and its values.
`getActiveVals` uses `filter` got only elements that are checked. Another `map` converts result object to its value string i.e. "d_e"

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.difficultyFi');
const difficultyVals = [...checkboxes].map(e => ({ el: e, val: e.value }));
const getActiveVals = () => difficultyVals.filter(({el}) => el.checked).map(({val}) => val);

checkboxes.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('change', () => console.log(getActiveVals())));
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="difficultyFi" value="d_e" checked> easy<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="difficultyFi" value="d_m"> moderate<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="difficultyFi" value="d_h"> hard<br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that you could specify certain attributes as [parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) in the function. Simply stating `element, value` gave me the result I required instead of using `this.value()`.

```js
var availableDifficulty = [];
var activeDifficulty = [];
var difficultyFi = document.querySelectorAll('.difficultyFi');

difficultyFi.forEach( function(element, value) {

    var difVal = element.value;

    availableDifficulty.push( difVal );

    if ( element.hasAttribute( 'checked' ) ) {
        activeDifficulty.push( difVal );
    }

});

console.log( activeDifficulty );
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input difficultyFi" type="checkbox" role="switch" value="d_e" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="d_e">Easy</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input difficultyFi" type="checkbox" role="switch" value="d_m" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="d_m">Moderate</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input difficultyFi" type="checkbox" role="switch" value="d_h" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="d_h">Hard</label>
</div>
```